# Material UI - Wierd KeyboardDateTimePicker interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So, we are using the KeyboardDateTimePicker from Material UI.
But we have a weird interaction when changed the data with the keyboard.
As you can see in the picture, all numbers are moving to the right.
How can we overcome this?

[image]

[image]

This is our code:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                    name="startDateTime"
                    variant="inline"
                    ampm={false}
                    label="Van"
                    value={request.startDateTime}
                    onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                    invalidDateMessage={'Ongeldig moment'}
                    maxDate={request.endDateTime}
                    disableFuture
                    format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                    disabled={isLoading}
                    strictCompareDates={true}
                    maxDateMessage={'Moment mag niet na einde'}
                />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: I found this same behavior. Similarly it sometimes won't allow you to type double-digit values for the month, day, or other parts. It seems like a WIP. Not a finished product. The popup stuff seems fine though.